# Ubuntu Shell Script giving wrong output

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh, scripting-language

I'm trying to learn basics of shell scripting when I run the following code my terminal return "None of the condition met" but when I run it on an [online shell](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) I get "a is equal to b" can anyone explain the reason for this.

Source:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=10
b=10

if [ $a == $b ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "None of the condition met"
fi
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu `/bin/sh` is [dash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh). You could do something like,

```
#!/bin/sh

a=10
b=10

if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "None of the condition met"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator is not portable, and apparently the shell you have installed as `/bin/sh` is using a builtin version of `[` that does not recognize that operator.  Just replace it with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

`sh(1)` in ubuntu is a symbol link to `dash(1)`:

```
$ which sh | xargs ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jan 20 2015 /bin/sh -> dash
```

according to its man page,
there's no `==` operator in `test(1)` or `[`. `==` is an extended operator for `bash(1)`.

There's two ways to change:

- if you want to compare two integer, use '-eq' instead
- if you want to compare two string, use '=' instead.

And both ways are posix-compatible.